# Create Principal in Guice Filter

Tags: authentication, servlets, guice

I am trying to implement a custom authentication filter in Guice. I receive the token, get the username and realm from the token and then create a Principal. Now I am stuck and I don't know how to set the Principal. It would be nice if I could just set it like this `request.setUserPrincipal(principal);`, but obviously I can't.

How can I do this?

My doFilter method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.length() > 0) {
        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
        if (token.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Credentials credentials = securityService.getCredentials(token);
                String username = credentials.getUsername();
                String realm = credentials.getRealm();
                Principal principal = new HttpPrincipal(username, realm);
                // request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
                LOGGER.info(credentials);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }
        }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet spec section 13.10 says:

> The container establishes the caller identity of a request prior to
>   dispatching the request to the servlet engine. The caller identity
>   remains unchanged throughout the processing of the request or until
>   the application sucessfully calls authenticate, login or logout on the
>   request.

That is the reason why there is no `setUserPrincipal`.

But there are good news. You can provide your own `getUserPrincipal` because you can provide your own `HttpServletRequest` object. Any servlet filter can do it. Look at your code, you are calling the chain method with two parameters: the request and the response. There is no need to pass the same objects that you receive.

The spec even provides you with a helper class: `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. You just create your own request class as a subclass of the wrapper and override any method that you want, like `getUserPrincipal`.